# Writing sanitizer function in Typescript to check for null, undefined and empty strings and getting error inside function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm writing a generic function in Typescript to take a string value and check to see if it is null, undefined or an empty string and return null or if it's an actual value return it trimmed.

The issue I'm running into ironically, is that inside the function on the second line at `return stringValue.trim();` I'm getting the error `Object is possibly null or undefined` and I'm not sure what kind of check I can do to fix that.

This is my function currently:

```
  const sanitize = (stringValue: string | undefined | null) => {
    let emptyString = '';
    let nullValue = null;
    let undefinedValue = undefined;

    if(typeof stringValue === emptyString || typeof stringValue === nullValue || typeof stringValue === undefinedValue){
      return null
    } else {
      return stringValue.trim();
    }
  }
```

Comment: `typeof` returns the [type as a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof), not the type itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use `typeof` here, simply compare the variables directly so that TypeScript knows you have already excluded those possible types, which guarantees that `stringValue` will not be `null` or `undefined`:

`if(stringValue === '' || stringValue === null || stringValue === undefined)`

Or, as @DBS mentioned, make use of [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values and simplify your statement to

`if (!stringValue)`

If you wanted to also have strings which contain only whitespace return as null, you could change your return statement to `return stringValue.trim() || null` to check if the trimmed value becomes `''`

As @DBS also mentioned, `typeof` returns the type as a string. Also `typeof` on a `null` object will return `'object'`, not `'null'`, making this even less applicable for this scenario. In general I've never really found myself needing to use `typeof`, except for some dynamic input validation

Comment: This is correct, but just as an interesting side note, due to JS's concept of things being "truthy", you could simply say `if(!stringValue){}` as null/undefined and empty strings are all falsey.

Comment: I tried to accept answer, but it says I have to wait 10 minutes haha

Comment: @DBS yup I just thought it'd more straightforward/obvious to keep the code in a similar format

Comment: @Josh no problem haha and these are good reads for a follow up on what DBS is saying [truthy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). Makes sanitizing, as you put it, much easier

Comment: This would fail Incase `stringValue="  "`. This would return an empty string instead of a null if the string contains multiple whitespaces

Comment: @YousufKhan not sure OP wanted a case for that, but that could easily be handled with `return stringValue.trim() || null`

Answer (score 0):

instead of the using the extra variables and to increase code readability, your working sanitize function can be written as

```
 const sanitize = (stringValue: string | undefined | null) => {
    if(typeof stringValue === "string"){
        return stringValue.trim();
    } else {
        return null
    }
  }
```

`typeof stringValue`  will return `string` if the type is string, and the `if` block will return the trimmed string. If the type is other than a string, we simply return `null`.

As @DBS mentioned, the above will not return null for empty strings. If you want to return null for empty strings as well, use the following version:

```
 const sanitize = (stringValue: string | undefined | null) => {
    if(typeof stringValue === "string" && stringValue.trim().length>0){
        return stringValue.trim();
    } else {
        return null
    }
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't catch the situation where the asker wants to return `null` for an empty string.

Comment: ah my bad, will cover that case as well with an edit. Thank you :)